# Open an arff file with scipy.io

Tags: python, pandas, arff

I am trying to load an arff file and convert the data to a pandas dataframe. The data is available at the [UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Chronic_Kidney_Disease), however, when I do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.io import arff


dataframe, meta = arff.loadarff('chronic_kidney_disease.arff')

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(dataframe)

dataframe.head()
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError:  yes value not in ('yes', 'no')
```

How could I load an arff file and convert the data to a dataframe?

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Comment: Have found a solution to this and posted below.

Comment: @Raj I provided the full code to read the data easily.

Answer (score 2):

The dataset '`chronic_kidney_disease.arff`' has the following problems.

1. It contains tabs.
2. Two tuples have anomalies in them. One of them has extra space and the other one has an extra ','.

To make the arff file to be read through loadarff, do the following

1. Replace all tabs with nothing. It can be done quickly with any rich text editor with a simple find and replace. I used Notepad++ to do this.
2. At line 60 in the file, there is an extra space in front of the value 'yes'. This needs to be removed.
3. At line 399 in the file, there is an extra ','. This needs to be removed as well.

After doing the above corrections the file is loading fine through loadarff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the dataset directly from [UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/chronic_kidney_disease), I suggest the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
with open('chronic_kidney_disease_full.arff', "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')
        data.append(line.split(','))


names = ['age', 'bp', 'sg', 'al', 'su', 'rbc', 'pc', 'pcc', 'ba',
         'bgr', 'bu',  'sc', 'sod', 'pot', 'hemo', 'pcv', 'wbcc',
         'rbcc', 'htn', 'dm', 'cad', 'appet', 'pe', 'ane',
         'class', 'no_name']
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data[145:], columns=names)
```

You can also find the `.csv` data in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/). [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/mansoordaku/ckdisease?select=kidney_disease.csv), you can download the `kidney_disease.csv`, which is the same data.